# Does central limit theorem apply to the following product case?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

All! I know the central limit theorem works for a lot of cases, and some variants including Lindeberg are also pretty useful, but now I met such product case, and wondering if some classical or variant of the CLT still works or not for $Z_n$:

\begin{align}
   Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i\right)
\end{align}
where $X_i, Y_i, ~i= 1, 2, \ldots, n $ are i.i.d, without loss of generality, you can think they follow i.i.d normal.  Would $Z_n$ be asymptotic normal or not then?

Comment: Try rewriting this as $Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n W_i\right)$ where $W_i=X_i+Y_i+X_iY_i$.  You are going to want $W_i$ to have a finite second moment

Comment: +1 but you're also going  to need a condition on the first moment; mere finiteness won't do